# Test Class for SOQL(CollaborationGroupFeed Object)

Tags: apex, soql

I'm new Apex coding, Could anybody help me fill out the test class?
I guess it is a simple soql query statement, and I wrote a test class, but I keep getting errors and I don't know why.
I got two error messages which are

1. Field is not wirteable: CollaborationGroupFeed.ParentId
2. DML operation Insert not allowed on List

Please help me~~

Here is my soql~

```
public with sharing class BB_GetChatterAll {
  
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static  List<sObject> getChatterAll() {

  sObject[] getChatterData = [SELECT Body, Title, CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate, ParentId, Parent.Name, Type FROM CollaborationGroupFeed ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC limit 30];

  return getChatterData;

}
```

and this is my test class

```
@isTest
  public class BB_GetChatterAllTest {

    @isTest
      static void getChatterAllTest() {

        List<CollaborationGroupFeed> getChatterData = new List<CollaborationGroupFeed>();
        for (Integer count = 0; count < 50; count++) {
          getChatterData.add(new CollaborationGroupFeed (ParentId ='000000000000000000'+count));
        }
            
        insert getChatterData;
       
        Test.startTest();
        BB_GetChatterAll.getChatterAll();
        Test.stopTest();
        CollaborationGroupFeed ACC = [SELECT ParentId from CollaborationGroupFeed LIMIT 1];
            System.assertEquals ( Integer.valueOf(ACC.ParentId) ,000000000000000000);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create objects of type *CollaborationGroupFeed*.

But even if you could in theory, your test class code would run into errors. This is because you are trying to set the field *ParentId* to an invalid reference. The ParentId you tried to specify for your objects in the for loop is (18 zeroes) + count, and will 1. not work because Ids in Salesforce are either 15- or 18 characters long and 2. because they simply do not point to any record in the database (no record with Id = '000000000000000000') exists.

What you can do in your Test Class however is the following:

1. create a CollaborationGroup record
2. create a Feeditem with *ParentId* = *the Id of the CollaborationGroup*
3. Query all CollaborationGroupFeed
4. the result should be one CollaborationGroupFeed

By creating a FeedItem on the CollaborationGroup like that, a CollaborationGroupFeed object will automatically be created as well. I understand this may be hard to find out, but from the [Salesforce Object Reference for CollaborationGroupFeed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroupfeed.htm):

> Represents a single feed item on a Chatter group feed. A group feed
> shows posts and comments about the group. This object is available in
> API version 19.0 and later.

*Feed item* in this case is equivalent to an object named *FeedItem* related to the CollaborationGroup (related by *ParentId*!).

If you have questions, feel free to adjust your post or simply write a comment.

References:

Salesforce Object References for

[CollaborationGroup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroup.htm)

[FeetItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The object CollaborationGroupFeed supports only delete(), describeSObjects(), getDeleted(), getUpdated(), query(), retrieve() calls(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroupfeed.htm)

You need to create CollaborationGroup record and make updates to create CollaborationGroupFeed records in your test class